# DateTime.Ticks property value

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

Shouldn't the value of `DateTime.Now.Ticks` be the same as `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`? I checked their values and found that the difference represents my current time zone offset from UTC. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you expect them to be the same? The dates/times are different - so their representations in ticks are different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is part of how the objects were designed.

In other libraries and languages (for example, JavaScript's `Date` type), the value is bound to UTC, and usually uses an epoch of 1970-01-01.

But in .NET, the `Ticks` value is related to the same frame of reference that the `Years`, `Months`, `Days`, and other properties are based on.  It uses an epoch of 0001-01-01.

In `DateTime`, there's a property called `Kind`:

- If the kind is `DateTimeKind.Utc`, then you know the value is related to UTC.
- If the kind is `DateTimeKind.Local`, then you know the value is related to the local time zone.
- If the kind is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, then you have no idea what time zone reference you have.  You simply have a date and time.

You see the difference between `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks` and `DateTime.Now.Ticks` as your current time zone offset, because `DateTime.Now` has `Local` kind, while `DateTime.UtcNow` has `Utc` kind.  So the ticks of `DateTime.Now` are based on your local time zone, while ticks from `DateTime.UtcNow` are based on UTC.

The `DateTimeOffset` type can be used to counteract this problem.  The `Ticks` are still relative to the value shown, but the `Offset` can be used to always adjust these ticks back to a UTC frame of reference.

If you don't like this, as many do not, an alternative is to use types from the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library.

By the way, I cover this information in even greater detail, and compare it to other programming languages in my Pluralsight course, [Date and Time Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/date-time-fundamentals).

Answer (score 0):

It's different because the time zones are different.